# ExtJs 6 or 7 focus treelist item into view

Tags: extjs, extreact

I have this treelist with a toolbar that I use to create new elements (it's a document list) and I want to focus the newly created item. I can select it but I don't seem to find a way of focusing it:

```
const selected = documents.treeStore.getAt(documents.treeStore.findExact(
    "documentId", current.id
));

if (selected) {
    tree.cmp.setSelection(selected);

    const node = tree.cmp.getSelection();// maybe redundant
    // how do I focus this node into view?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by focus you mean that the element should appear in the visibility range, you can use this method
[ensureVisible](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.panel.Table.html#method-ensureVisible)

Answer (score 0):

```
const selected = documents.treeStore.getAt(documents.treeStore.findExact(
    "documentId", current.id
));

if (selected) {
    var path = [];

    do {
        path.push(selected.getId());
    }while (selected = selected.getRefOwner());

    tree.cmp.expandPath('/' + path.reverse().join('/'), {focus:true});
}
```

Comment: Title says extjs 6/7

Comment: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.tree.View.html#method-focusRow